# Drupal - can't even delete unpacked Basic theme from disk

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

https://www.drupal.org/project/basic

Basic theme is good for beginners, they say. Basic's goal is to provide themers the building blocks needed to get their designs up and running quickly and simply, they say.

I can't install this theme with url - it has too many MBs, I can't install theme by unpacking and copying it to theme folder, but I can't even delete it from my harddisk because it has an incredible amount of repeating empty folders:

> File name is too long for destionation folder

WTF? What an idiot did this and recommended it for beginners?

Answer (score 1):

It will be the grunt folder that is causing the problem it has 8000 plus files in it.

Grunt is used to compile your SASS and js files, you would normally run this locally so it does not need to be pushed up to the server. You can use SASS's built in watch function and not use grunt at all or not use SASS and just edit the css, but Grunt should make your life easier.

Comment: but how can i delete it from my disc?

Comment: If you have ssh access the amount of files shouldn't be a problem, if not navigate into the grunt folder and try deleting it in smaller chunks.